# in an if/else statement, e.preventDefault() is not performing 100% to the conditions

Tags: jquery

This function (using `option:selected`) changes the CSS and HTML of `<div class="item">0</div>` to simulate a kind of progress bar app. The problem is that it exceeds `100%`. So the `if` statements are not correct or something here is wrong? Any clues?

```
$(function(){
    $('#selectChoice').change(function() {
        $('option:selected', this).each(function() {
            var id = $('#selectChoice option:selected').attr('id');
            $('#' + id + 'Item').css("color", "#f00").css("font-weight", "bold");
        });
    });

    $('#plus25').on('click', function() {
        var id = $('#selectChoice option:selected').attr('id');
        $('#' + id + 'Item').html(function(i, value) {
            var newWidth = parseInt(value * 1 + 25);
            var e = window.event;
            $('#' + id + 'Item').css('width', newWidth + '%');
            if (value <= 75){
                return newWidth;
            } else { 
                e.PreventDefault();}
            });
        });
    });
```

The following condition is also doing strange things at `0`

```
if (value >= 25) {
    return newWidth;
}
```

A complete version can be seen [here](http://georgehowell.biz/test/index.html)

Comment: the following IE bug fix is thanks to @amitthk: 
                    else { safePreventDefault(e);}
                    });
                });
  
  safePreventDefault=function(evt){
        //fix for IE Bug
        evt = evt || window.event;
        if (evt) {
            evt.returnValue = false;
        }
        if ((evt)&&(evt.preventDefault))
        { evt.preventDefault(); }
    };

Comment: getting `e is undefined`. use `function(e)`. remove `var e = window.event;`

Comment: thanks @Parth Trivedi.  maybe `var e = evt || window.event;` needs to be defined somewhere else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the `event` object passed in to the `click` handler, not the global `window.event`. Also, the method is `preventDefault()` in lowercase. Try this:

```
$('#plus25').on('click', function(e) { // Note the 'e' parameter here
    var id = $('#selectChoice option:selected').attr('id');
    $('#' + id + 'Item').html(function(i, value) {
        var newWidth = parseInt(value * 1 + 25);
        $('#' + id + 'Item').css('width', newWidth + '%');
        if (value <= 75) {
            return newWidth;
        } else {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks @ Rory McCrossan, but it is still exceeding 100%

Comment: Use `newWidth < 100` instead of `value < 75`.

Comment: I think the `if`/`else` needs more conditions.. just what exactly is eluding me. Maybe `else if`

Comment: You're probably best to start a new question for it, as this one was about the use of `preventDefault()`